# Unique combination of 2 columns, order independent

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, create-table, unique-constraint

I have a table like this, which represents friendships between persons in a social network

```
CREATE TABLE friendships
(
    requester INT,
    acceptor INT
);
```

Now I want unique combination of (requester, acceptor), order independent. Normal unique constraint, `UNIQUE (requester, acceptor)`, is not enough for this case because if there is already, for example, one row with the combination (1, 2) the combination (2, 1) is still allowed, and I don't want that.

How to solve this? I'm using MySQL.

Comment: You can also build the logic into the query itself, but obviously that's unnecessary if using 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting in MySQL 8.0.13, you can create an index on an expression.  That allows you to do:

```
create unique index unq_friendships_requestor_acceptor on
     friendships( (least(requestor, acceptor)) , (greatest(requestor, acceptor)) );
```

You should also declare these two columns as `NOT NULL`.

For older versions. GMB's answer is appropriate.

Comment: I'm using MySQL 8.0.20 but I'm getting an error:
mysql> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_friendships_requestor_acceptor ON  friendships(least(requestor, acceptor), greatest(requestor, acceptor));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'requestor, acceptor), greatest(requestor, acceptor))' at line 1

Comment: Just looked at documentation and 

"create unique index unq_friendships_requestor_acceptor on
     friendships((least(requestor, acceptor)), (greatest(requestor, acceptor)));"

 is working. Just wrap the expressions in parentheses. @GordonLinoff edit your answer, add the parentheses. Can't edit it, have to add at least 6 characters by stackoverflow laws

Comment: @MariaGabriela . . . Sorry about that.  I'm not sure why MySQL imposes those parentheses.

Comment: For anyone coming from the future, it doesn't look like MariaDB can do this.

Comment: Scratch that -- it can be achieved on MariaDB by adding the index to some virtual column.

Answer (score 2):

A simple method is:

```
create table friendships (
    requester int,
    acceptor int,
    check(requester < acceptor),
    unique (requester, acceptor)
);
```

With this setup, you just cannot insert type `(2, 1)`. You need to make it `(1, 2)`, and the unique constraint prevents duplicates.

If you want something more flexible, another solution is to use generated columns, that are available in recent MySQL versions:

```
create table friendships (
    requester int,
    acceptor int,
    v1 int generated always as (least(requester, acceptor)),
    v2 int generated always as (greatest(requester, acceptor)),
    unique (v1, v2)
);
```

This lets you insert either `(2, 1)` or `(1, 2)`; once of the tuples is insterted, the other cannot.

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00ad42c75ba3cc464454486787ab663c)**:

```
insert into friendships(requester, acceptor) values(2, 1);
-- ok

insert into friendships(requester, acceptor) values(1, 2);
-- ERROR: Duplicate entry '1-2' for key 'friendships.v1'
```

Comment: But that forces requester to be less than acceptor? If yes I don't want that

Comment: Worth to mention, that check constraints aren't working before MySQL version 8.0.16 (See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html). They're parsed but ignored, i.e. aren't preventing data that is invalid to be entered into the table.

Comment: @MariaGabriela: the first solution forces requester to be less than acceptor, not the second one (but the second solution requires MySQL 8.0.16, as sticky bit points out).